# How do you use visual studio tools for office with xml ribbon UI to get a user control to come up when a button is click?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vsto, ribbon

I am using XML ribbons for my UI in VSTO. In Micrsoft word, sometimes when you click a button in the ribbons, a user control pops up. How you you get it to pop up?

Comment: Do you have an example for one of the existing Ribbon buttons in Word? As far as I know, there is no Ribbon-specific feature to do this, and I would implement it as a regular .NET dialog / pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just used a [Custom task pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx).